# Correct SPF Record Usage?

Tags: domain, spf, txt-record, dns-zone

My txt entry for my domain is as follows:

> "v=spf1 a ip4:aspmx.googlemail.com ptr:aspmx.googlemail.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com -all"

I have also tried to use `ptr` in addition to `a`. However, I'm not sure I fully understand the difference between them. PTR seems to do a reverse lookup on the domain, whereas A simply references the A record in the zone file?

The header response from Gmail is:

> Received-SPF: unknown (google.com: domain of do-not-reply@example.com uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: ))
>
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=permerror (google.com: domain of do-not-reply@example.com uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: )) smtp.mail=do-not-reply@example.com; dkim=neutral (no key) header.i=@example.com

Answer (score 3):

The correct TXT record for googlemail is "v=spf1 include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all". You should also note the usage of `~all` versus `-all`.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that is the cause because it's complaining about the mydomain.com query: "domain of do-not-reply@mydomain.com uses a mechanism not recognized by this client", but I'm going to try.

The world of trial and error begins. 

Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is the meaning of ~all versus -all? The documentation is a bit weak on this: http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page: Please see this page from Google: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723

> Publishing an SPF record that uses -all instead of ~all may result in delivery problems. See >Google IP address ranges for details about the addresses for the Google Apps mail servers.

EDIT: You should also *really* be using DKIM. With DMARC standardization approaching, this is highly important.